# Unable to edit snippet with Chrome on Linux

Tags: bug, edits, stack-snippets

There is some bug with editing the questions with code snippets (Chrome/Linux).

It's not possible to edit the post containing the snippet - you can place cursor at any position but keys pressed while inside the textarea do nothing (well, <kbd>tab</kbd> works) and cursor is moved to the end of text.

Problem does not occur with Firefox/Linux.

Browser: Chrome 54.0.2840.100
System: Linux Mint 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was happening because of installed extension `Emoji Input by EmojiStuff.com`.

Removing this extension fixed the problem.

Comment: I was afflicted with exactly the same problem! Thank you. :-)